# Set Material Ui button background

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to change the button background using the sx style props. So far I've been trying to use the following pattern "MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root" to override the style:

```
<Button
                className="font-semibold"
                sx={{
                  boxShadow: "none",
                  color: "#4a92fe",
                  border: "2px solid #eaecf0",
                  "& MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root":
                    {
                      backgroundColor: "red",
                    },
                }}
                variant="contained"
                fullWidth
                onClick={onClickApplyHandler}
              >
                Aplicar
              </Button>
```

Unfortunately, I've not succeed with this one. What is the appropriate way to set the background color using the sx prop?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because there is no "MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root" under the Button component. The MUI  Button component is like :

```html
<button class="MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-containedSizeMedium MuiButton-fullWidth MuiButtonBase-root  css-kleyt8-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root" tabindex="0" type="button">
  Aplicar
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
```

so you should do this:

```html
 <Button
  variant="contained"
  fullWidth
  sx={{ 
    boxShadow: "none",
    color: "#4a92fe",
    border: "2px solid #eaecf0",
    backgroundColor: "pink",
  }}
  onClick={onClickApplyHandler}
    >
    Aplicar
  </Button>
```

Comment: I tried setting the backgroundColor in sx props before. Actually bg color is not changing either with the code you shared which is stressful because it should be simple as that!